# Unusual shape of a textarea?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Usually textareas are rectangular or square, like this:

[image: Usual textarea]

But I want a custom-shaped textarea, like this, for example:

[image: Custom-shaped textarea]

How is this possible?

Comment: Hmm. I wish there was something built-in for this. Like 'box-shape: circle' with CSS. :/

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to draw following shape using css?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20091275/how-to-draw-following-shape-using-css)

Comment: check out CodeMirror for some inspiration.  But I don't think it supports word-wrapping functionality.

Comment: Welcome to the most overused web trope for the next three years!

Comment: It's kinda shocking how all this here has happened just today... Great question. (BTW, @uosɐſ: CodeMirror does support word wrapping. What it probably doesn't support is custom shaped textareas. ;) )

Comment: Completely unrelated: May I ask what context you're planning to use this in? I mean, I can't really figure a scenario in which this would be useful, so I'd like some inspiration on that.

Comment: @lunakid - oh yeah, I meant float-wrapping (or whatever the correct term is)  I was thinking that if you could put in transparent blocks - for the example, in the top right and left corners - then that could make the effect.

Comment: *Everybody* is missing a **critical problem**. Using a `<div>` to store text is *not* a good solution. It may help design, and might even be acceptable for read-only text (which completely defeats the purpose of `contenteditable`), but it’s **not good** for text input from a user. A div (even a contenteditable one) is not a standard input element like a normal form element, therefore, it will not be treated like one, and so its contents will *not* be saved by browsers in case of crashes. Using a div leads to **data-loss**. See [this example](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/53294/).

Comment: Actually this should be closed as "Demonstrated a minimal understanding of the problem being solved"

Comment: So, where do you want to see the vertical scrollbar?

Comment: @Paranoid where is your effort?

Comment: I don't really see how this would be useful, but at least using two textareas would work everywhere, but would also require a lot of work figuring out the arrow keys between the textareas, word wrapping and other stuff. I started on a small plugin -> **http://jsfiddle.net/2jBx9/1/** but soon figured out how much work it was, and how useless it seemed, but it's there for anyone wanting to finish it.

Comment: Flagged for not having attempted solutions and why they didn't work. See @Mr.Alien's post

Comment: I'd rather see it as part of wiki than closed due to relevance and attention it has received from the community

Comment: @JaakKütt It was closed but again it was re-opened, but anyways, no one listens [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214619/what-should-we-really-ask-on-stackoverflow)... and not wiki, but it should be closed atleast

Comment: The correct answer to this question is really "tell whoever asked you to do this that it's impossible, to save them making an idiot of themselves".

Answer (score 263, accepted):

## Introduction

First, there are many solutions, proposed in other posts. I think this one is currently (in 2013) the one which can be compatible with the largest number of browsers, because it doesn't need any CSS3 properties. However, the method will not work on [browsers which doesn't support](http://caniuse.com/contenteditable) `contentdeditable`, be careful.

## Solution with a div `contenteditable`

As proposed by [@Getz](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20728196/1433392), you can use a div with `contenteditable` and then shape it with some div on it. Here is an example, with two blocks which float at the upper left and the upper right of the main div:

[image: The result with Firefox 28]

As you can see, you have to **play a little with the borders** if you want the same result as you requested in your post. The main div has the blue border on every side. Next, red blocks has to be sticked to hide top borders of the main div, and you need to apply border to them only on particular sides (*bottom and left* for the right block, *bottom and right* for the left).

After that, you can get the content via Javascript, when the "*Submit*" button is triggered for example. And I think you can also handle the rest of the CSS (`font-size`, `color`, etc.) :)

## Full code sample

```css
.block_left {
  background-color: red;
  height: 70px;
  width: 100px;
  float: left;
  border-right: 2px solid blue;
  border-bottom: 2px solid blue;
}

.block_right {
  background-color: red;
  height: 70px;
  width: 100px;
  float: right;
  border-left: 2px solid blue;
  border-bottom: 2px solid blue;
}

.div2 {
  background-color: white;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  border: 2px solid blue;
}

.parent {
  height: 300px;
  width: 500px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="block_left"></div>
  <div class="block_right"></div>
  <div class="div2" contenteditable="true">
    "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut..."
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Great solution but with a bug: `You can't apply a border color for the editable section keeping the two corner div's background-color:white`. Isn't it? Still this will win. +1

Comment: I don't see the problem. It's possible to set a background-color:white on this: http://jsfiddle.net/qgfP6/6/. But, you have to set a background, otherwise bad things happened: http://jsfiddle.net/qgfP6/7/ (you can see border of the parent container...)

Comment: There is a workaround requiring more divs, though.
The parrent element which is transparent and without border, filled with overlapping divs with borders and backgrounds AND with padding divs to create desired effect.

Comment: @MaximeLorant I was telling about those `bad things` only. Those would be the side-effects of the situation I just asked about and what you have done in the fiddle. But it certainly is a really good solution. Thanx for the clarification.

Comment: Brilliant answer! And here I was gonna go and suggest something along the lines of using two text areas close together with content split between the two.

Comment: Awesome answer but I think the `<div class="div3"></div>` is redundant. Am I wrong?

Comment: Indeed, it's useless here. Some remaining from the author code.

Comment: **Do not use this answer as-is**, unless you really want to have rich-text markup. When I drag a link to a text area, I expect to see the URL pasted in the textarea. In contentEditable divs, I see "`<�strong><�a href="http://jsfiddle.net/qgfP6/1/" rel="nofollow">http://jsfiddle.net/qgfP6/1/<�/a><�/strong>.`" (dragged from link in Firefox to Chrome) or "`Edit fiddle - JSFiddle`" (dragged from Chrome's omnibox to Chrome). Anything that breaks the expectations of an input field should not be used for "enhancing the appearance".

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/2758467/rajesh-paul What do you want Bengali? Everything is working properly!Excellent solve! Thank you too much Maxime Lorant

Answer (score 115):

In the near future we can use so called `css-shapes` to achieve this. A div with the `contenteditable` attribute set to `true` combined with `css-shapes` can make a text area any kind of shape.

Currently Chrome Canary already [supports](https://src.chromium.org/viewvc/blink?revision=159989&view=revision) `css-shapes`. An example what is possible with css-shapes is:

[image]

Here they are using a polygon shape to define the text-flow. It should be possible to create two polygons to match the shape you want for your textarea.

More information about `css-shapes` has been written at: http://sarasoueidan.com/blog/css-shapes/

> To enable css-shapes in Chrome Canary:
>
> 1. Copy and paste
>      chrome://flags/#enable-experimental-web-platform-features into the
>      address bar, then press enter.
> 2. Click the 'Enable' link within that
>      section.
> 3. Click the 'Relaunch Now' button at the bottom of the
>      browser window.
>
>    from: http://html.adobe.com/webplatform/enable/

```css
.container {
  overflow: hidden;
  shape-inside: polygon(200.67px 198.00px, 35.33px 198.47px, 34.67px 362.47px, 537.00px 362.74px, 535.67px 196.87px, 388.33px 197.00px, 386.67px 53.53px, 201.33px 53.53px);
  font-size: 0.8em;
}
/** for red border **/

.container:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 8px;
  left: 8px;
  width: 190px;
  height: 190px;
  background-color: white;
  border-right: 1px solid red;
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
}
.container:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 8px;
  right: 8px;
  width: 190px;
  height: 190px;
  background-color: white;
  border-left: 1px solid red;
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container" contenteditable="true">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque convallis diam lacus, id lacinia quam interdum quis. Ut vitae dignissim lorem, nec lobortis turpis. Fusce non fringilla nulla, eu blandit urna. Nulla facilisi. Nunc tristique, mauris vitae
  tincidunt egestas, eros metus dapibus sapien, quis tincidunt sem dui ac purus. Morbi lobortis, quam sit amet consequat aliquam, elit mi rutrum erat, id tempus turpis turpis et sem. Vivamus tempor mollis porttitor. Sed elementum nisl sit amet sapien
  auctor imperdiet. Sed suscipit convallis nisi, in dignissim risus placerat suscipit. Sed vel lorem eu massa vulputate pretium. Nulla eget dolor sed elit gravida condimentum non vel lorem. Vivamus pretium, augue sed aliquet ultricies, neque nibh porttitor
  libero, a tristique elit mi eu nibh. Vestibulum erat arcu, condimentum eleifend adipiscing ut, euismod eu libero. In pharetra iaculis lorem, at consectetur nisi faucibus eu.

</div>
```

Polygon created with: http://betravis.github.io/shape-tools/polygon-drawing/

**Result**

[image]

http://jsfiddle.net/A8cPj/1/

Comment: Fiddle and example didn't work for me. The text goes below polygon and stays hidden below it. I tested with Chromium 49, Firefox 44

Comment: Just seen this, this will be a nightmare to get it responsive.

Answer (score 62):

Maybe it's possible with [Content Editable](http://html5demos.com/contenteditable) ?

It's not a textarea, but if you succeed to create a div with this shape, it could work.

I think it's not possible with just textarea...

A little example: http://jsfiddle.net/qgfP6/5/

```
<div contenteditable="true">
</div>
```

Answer (score 23):

You could work with a contenteditable div, with two corners divs:

```
<div style="border:1px blue solid ; width: 200px; height: 200px;" contenteditable="true">
  <div style="float:left; width:50px; height: 50px; border: 1px solid blue" contenteditable="false"></div>
  <div style="float:right; width:50px; height: 50px;  border: 1px solid blue" contenteditable="false"></div>
  hello world, hello worldsdf asdf asdf sdf asdf asdf
</div>
```

Comment: It needs some more JS work to take care of all the different use cases. But the basis is there.

Answer (score 20):

You could also do this with [CSS Regions](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-regions/)

> With Regions, you can use CSS properties to flow content into existing
>   styled containers, specifying any container order you choose,
>   regardless of their position on the page.

[(Web Platform)](http://html.adobe.com/webplatform/layout/regions/)

[image]

[Currently supported in WebKit Nightly, Safari 6.1+ and iOS7 and already usable in chrome and opera after enabling the flag: enable-experimental-web-platform-features - [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/css-regions), [Web Platform](http://html.adobe.com/webplatform/layout/regions/) ]

### [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/8gMQG/3/)

So you could make that textarea shape by flowing the text through 2 regions, and edit it by adding contenteditable on the content.

### Markup

```
<div id="box-a" class="region"></div>
<div id="box-b" class="region"></div>
<div id="content" contenteditable>text here</div>
```

### (Relevant) CSS

```
#content {
     -ms-flow-into: article;
    -webkit-flow-into: article;
}

.region {
    -ms-flow-from: article;
    -webkit-flow-from: article;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    padding: 0 1px;
    margin: auto;
    left:0;right:0;
    border: 2px solid lightBlue;
}

#box-a {
    top: 10px;
    background: #fff;
    z-index: 1;
    border-bottom: none;
}

#box-b {
    top: 210px;
    width: 400px;
    overflow: auto;
    margin-top: -2px;
}
```

The result:

[image]

For more info about regions - here's a good aricle: [CSS3 regions: Rich page layout with HTML and CSS3](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/html5/articles/css3-regions.html)

Comment: Nice! Although it is barely supported (most users don't want to have to get chrome canary and enable experimental flags to use a website), this is definitely the way it "should" be done

Comment: Indeed... Unfortunetly, it doesn't work yet on Firefox (even on Alpha) and others, and has a bad smell of vendor prefixes :(
But the method is interesting and has to be used in some months/years.

Comment: css regions, css shapes, css filters...what else is there i k

Comment: @MuhammadUmer ... css exclusions

Answer (score 18):

A long line of text in the box will drop the cursor down past the middle edges and I can't seem to fix that.

```
**[Fiddle Diddle][1]**
```

```css
    #wrap {
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    #inner {
        height: 350px;
        width: 500px;
        border: 1px solid blue;
    }
    #textContent {
        word-wrap: break-word;
        word-break: break-all;
        white-space: pre-line;
    }
    #left, #right {
        height: 50%;
        width: 25%;
        margin-top: -1px;
        padding: 0;
        border: 1px solid blue;
        border-top-color: white;
        margin-bottom: 5px;
    }
    #right {
        margin-left: 5px;
        float: right;
        margin-right: -1px;
        border-right-color: white;
    }
    #left {
        margin-right: 5px;
        float: left;
        margin-left: -1px;
        border-left-color: white;
    }
```

```html
<div id="wrap">
  <div id="inner">
     <div id="left"></div>
     <div id="right"></div>
     <span id="textContent" contenteditable>The A B Cs</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
[1]: http://jsfiddle.net/yKSZV/
```

Answer (score 8):

That's not possible sire! A textarea is generally a rect or square box, where you can type in.

However, to make something like that you can use 2 textarea's and then give them a specified width and height. Otherwise I don't think its gonna happen!

Second method would be to make an editable element.

http://jsfiddle.net/afzaal_ahmad_zeeshan/at2ke/

The code is:

```
<div contenteditable="true">
   This text can be edited by the user.
</div>
```

Using this, you can make any element editable! You can give dimensions to it, and it will work! You will get it just as a textarea.

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_Editable

Comment: No, you're wrong. Even he used `div`s instead of textarea. Because textarea cannot be modified into shaped! :)  @Markasoftware So you're wrong while downvoting this answer! .. since this is just the same answer as his. The only thing that is not present here is the image and the code to make the editable div with that shape!

Comment: What? Oh come on brother, if you want to keep me downvoted for no reason you're most welcome! My Answer was posted at : 9:58 he posted the answer at 10:10 :/ I was first to answer this question..@Markasoftware you can go and see the time for yourself. I am not upvoted much only because I did not provide the code. Howver, I posted the answer in the TOP 3 answerers..

Comment: lol actually when i go to the "oldest" tab it shows that your answer is second oldest

Comment: It is because of the fact that it is not much upvoted! I am everytime active here, so how can I post lately? And this one was a simple answe. So can you please remove the downvote? :)

Answer (score 5):

If you combine [CSS shapes](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-shapes/) with `contenteditable` this can be done in webkit browsers.

First you have to enable the flag: enable-experimental-web-platform-features

Then restart your webkit browser and then check this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/eSMyV/2/) out !

This method will work for non-standard shapes as well.

### Markup

```
 <div class="shape" contenteditable="true">
    <p>
     Text here
    </p>
  </div>
```

### CSS

```
.shape{
  -webkit-shape-inside: polygon(71.67px 204.00px,75.33px 316.47px,323.67px 315.47px,321.17px 196.00px,245.96px 197.88px,244.75px 87.76px,132.33px 87.53px,132.50px 202.26px);
  shape-inside: polygon(71.67px 204.00px,75.33px 316.47px,323.67px 315.47px,321.17px 196.00px,245.96px 197.88px,244.75px 87.76px,132.33px 87.53px,132.50px 202.26px);
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  text-align: justify;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

So how on earth did I get that polygon shape?

Go to [this site](http://betravis.github.io/shape-tools/polygon-drawing/) and make your own custom shape!

Notes about enabling the flag:
(from [here](http://html.adobe.com/webplatform/enable/))

> To enable Shapes, Regions, and Blend Modes:
>
> Copy and paste
>   chrome://flags/#enable-experimental-web-platform-features into the
>   address bar, then press enter. Click the 'Enable' link within that
>   section. 
>   Click the 'Relaunch Now' button at the bottom of the browser
>   window.

Comment: +1 for a (well documented, structured) solution, whether standard or not.

Comment: @kinokijuf You do realise that's how the standards come to be these days, right? In this case, Adobe came up with the shape proposal, and Webkit was the first one to implement it so far. Seeing as the Editor's Draft is from November, this probably can't be called a proprietary extension, and for all you know will end up more widely implemented and standardised later on. In the meantime non-Webkit users will get a rectangle, big deal. (Heck, Firefox still requires a prefix for `box-sizing`.)

Answer (score 4):

You can use **[Google web designer tool](https://www.google.com/webdesigner/)** for creating complex shapes using `HTML5-canvas and CSS`.

More over you will get other tools like typing tools to enter texts inside these shapes.

As the output file contains much code, providing a fiddle of a sample demo created using **Google Web Designer tool**

[**FIDDLE DEMO>>**](http://jsfiddle.net/LcxBw/1/)

Comment: Fiddle doesn't work for me (= text is not editable) on Chrome 31.0 / Windows 7.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen = text is not editable??? really i didn't get. What is the need of making it editable??

Comment: The question asks for something like a `<textarea>` (i.e. a box of editable text), but with a non-rectangular shape. Without the "editable" part, there's very little challenge here -- people have been doing flowed text in HTML ever since the introduction of floating images in HTML 2.0.

Comment: Fiddle updated with content editable property. Now text inside container is editable.

Comment: In the demo, I can edit 2 different texts, not 1 whole text. In Chrome 31.

Answer (score 1):

If, for whatever reason, you really need to support browsers that don't have `contenteditable`, you could probably do the same thing in JavaScript, by using events, although this is a very messy workaround.

Pseudocode:

```
focused=false;
when user clicks the div
    {
    focused=true;
    }
when user clicks outside the div
    {
    focused=false;
    }
when user presses a key
    {
    if (focused)
    {
    add character of key to div.innerHTML;
    }
    }
```