# How do I make a Star Wars introduction shaped textarea?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Normally, textareas are just boring old oblongs:

[image: An ordinary textarea with the opening text from The Empire Strikes Back.]

But is it possible to make a textarea shaped like the introduction to Star Wars?

[image: The famous opening text from The Empire Strikes Back.]

**Note: Inspired by [SO #20734620: unusual shape of a textarea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20728150/unusual-shape-of-a-textarea)—see comments.*

Update: Thanks to Niet the Dark Absol I was able to get it working. Just need to play with the font and color.
[image: Text area shaped like star wars crawl]

```
textarea {
width:600px;
height:500px;
transform:perspective(1000px) rotateX(45deg);
display:block;
margin:0 auto;
text-align: center;
line-height:200%;
color: yellow;
background-color: black;
font-size: 1.75em;
}
```

Comment: This question is a verbatim copy of [SO #20728150](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20728150/unusual-shape-of-a-textarea), right down to the greengrocer's apostrophe in the original post. The only differences are the title, the images and the intended effect. A very charitable interpretation is that you meant it to be a follow-on question from the original; if so, you could have just acknowledged that instead of copying it wholesale and implying coincidence in the comments there. :(

Comment: @JordanGray I didn't mean to offend. I was simply trying to add a little levity into an awesome question. I figured that enough people were looking at that one that at the time I wrote this one, that if I did mine as a parody it wouldn't ruffle too many feathers.

Comment: @wormtown It's _very_ easy to "ruffle people's feathers" on StackOverflow. If you think there is a _slight_ chance that a post will ruffle someone's feathers, the post will probably be closed or deleted within an hour.

Comment: @RyanCarlson I will definitely keep that in mind. Thanks.

Comment: @wormtown That's understandable; it just wasn't clear from your comment on the other question that this was intended as homage or parody. I don't think any of the people who voted to close are trying to be killjoys or reactionary, so perhaps if you explain that in the question it might be reopened?

Comment: @JordanGray Duly noted. I'll update it now. Thanks!

Comment: @JordanGray Thanks for that edit. It's better than the one I was working on.

Comment: No problem. Like @Ryan said, it's easy to ruffle feathers here (or, indeed, over the Internet in general), and it sounds like you were just trying to make a good-faith attempt at homage which fell a bit flat. Easy enough to do! :)

Comment: PS: as something of an apology for flagging this question instead of asking you first, here's [my own attempt](http://dabblet.com/gist/8098547). The font for the original opening crawl is based on Franklin Gothic; it's easy enough to find online, and not too expensive to get a web font license. Happy holidays!

Comment: @JordanGray Wow! That is awesome. Happy Holidays to you. I would never have come up with that background image - such a better idea than using an image.

Comment: For what it's worth, I would in fact close this question because I'm being a killjoy. SO is not a comedy writing venue, it's terrible enough in Amazon reviews.

Comment: @millimoose I appreciate that sentiment. Personally, I'm treating this as honest curiosity, expressed humorously, about how to achieve a prescribed effect with CSS rather than an attempt at humour dressed up as a coding question—which is, according to the author, their intention.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try a 3D transform:

```
#starwarstextareaofawesome {
    width:600px;
    height:500px;
    transform:perspective(1000px) rotateX(45deg);
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/PBnf5/)

Comment: I was coming up with the same answer. He's a demo with a div: http://jsbin.com/oteJIru/1/edit?html,css,output

Comment: This is a good solution. My problem is that the scrolling speed is still too fast. I tried setting warp to negative parsecs but that just made everything smaller.

Comment: The scrolling speed should be the same as any other element with a scrollbar. How are you trying to scroll it?

Comment: @yitwail Yes, but you will have to devote an entire squad to it.

Comment: @BillCriswell Ideally, I'd like the automatic scrolling speed to be readable. But no matter what I do, those stars in the background come at me like gangbusters.

Comment: May the force be with us

Comment: @yitwail It won't break, at least. You'll just have a normal textarea.