# how can i accomplish this jquery hover/click effect? (link)(image)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to make buttons like this for my website and have no idea where to begin. I would like the simplest way possible to accomplish/customize this hover/click animation effect. This works perfectly on mobile browsers as well as desktops.

When you hover over the clear button it animates a white background originating from the center of the button and spreading to the left and right.

It would be amazing if you could provide a functioning js fiddle. Thanks so much, everyone! I really appreciate your support! :)

http://www.treadsack.com

[image: This is an example of the animation that occurs when you hover over the about us button]

Comment: You misunderstood the sense of this site. http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: It is not do with JQuery but CSS3. Some CSS3 transition generator exists : http://www.css3maker.com/css3-transition.html

Comment: Actually these types of questions are increasing day by day, but some luckily get popular - http://stackoverflow.com/q/20728150/1542290

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/UQTY2/233/

Comment: For my own personal learning, created the following effect from scratch with the following minimalist HTML/CSS http://jsfiddle.net/hadynz/MweDb/

Comment: @hady your solution seemed to be the best since it is short and to the point... but.. for some reason when i copy it over to my site the button becomes the length of the screen : 100% and the hover effect doesn't work.. It works in the js fiddle.. any idea why its not working on my page?

Comment: There must be another CSS being applied on the anchor that is making it behave so - hard to confirm without seeing your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow [this link on codrops](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/06/13/creative-button-styles/)

```
.btn-6d {
    border: 2px dashed #226fbe;
}

.btn-6d:hover {
    background: transparent;
    color: #226fbe;
}
```

Comment: You will get all types of animation and effects from there easily. Accept answer if done.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at these http://tympanus.net/Development/CreativeButtons/ the source code and tutorial are here http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/06/13/creative-button-styles/