# wrap div around other divs

Tags: html, css, word-wrap

I'm trying to do get a div to wrap around 2 other divs. Like this:

[image]

Is this possible? I tried with `float:left;` and have the small divs be `display:block;` but it didn't work.

Inside each div, I will add pictures:

[image]

Comment: Check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20728150/unusual-shape-of-a-textarea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/TVCC8/1/

Float the two right containers and keep the large container as a block element.  Display the boxes inside the large block element as inline-block.

```
<div id='wrapper'>
<div id='one'><ul><li></li><li></li></ul></div>
<div id='two'><ul><li></li><li></li></ul></div>
<div id='three'><ul>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>    
    <li></li>
    <li></li>

 </ul></div>
```

And the CSS:

```
ul {list-style-type: none; margin:0; padding:0;}
li { width:20px; height:20px; margin:2px;}
#one {border: 1px solid blue; float: right;}
#one li {background-color: blue;}
#two {border: 1px solid green; float: right;}
#two li {background-color: green;}
#one ul, #two ul {margin:4px 1px 1px 1px;}
#three {border: 1px solid orange;}
#three ul {margin:4px;}
#three li {background-color: orange; display:inline-block; margin:0;}
#wrapper {width:105px;}
```

Comment: nice solution, but it is worth noting that ie8 and earlier don't support inline-block, so if it is a public website, you may want to avoid it.

Comment: Thanks. I believe IE8 does support inline-block. Something like modernizr.js should easily take care of the rest.

Comment: The ie8 implementation is very shaky, and often has some unexpected and very odd results. >ie8 is fine though. I tend to just avoid unsupported elements altogether where I can, so that I don't have to handle old IE separately with hacks / modernizr, unless the visual or functional rewards really are worth it.

Answer (score 2):

The natural flow of a non floating div would be to wrap around the floating right divs.
eg:

html

```
<div class="container">
<div class="right_box"></div>
<div class="right_box"></div>
<div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor  incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</div>
```

css

```
.container {border:1px solid #000; padding: 5px;text-align:justify;}
.right_box {border:1px solid #000; padding: 5px;background:  #ff0; margin: 10px; float:right; width:50px; height:50px;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/FAbr2/

EDIT:

The following jsfiddle would potentially solve the updated request (quickly / roughly done, but you'll get the idea)

http://jsfiddle.net/yvXkD/

html

```
<div class="container">
<div class="right_container">
    <div class="right_box"></div>
    <div class="right_box"></div>
</div>

<div class="right_box"></div>
<div class="right_box"></div>

 <div class="right_box"></div>
<div class="right_box"></div>

 <div class="right_box"></div>
<div class="right_box"></div>

 <div class="right_box"></div>
<div class="right_box"></div>

<div class="right_box"></div>
<div class="right_box"></div>

<div class="right_box"></div>
<div class="right_box"></div>

<div class="right_box"></div>
<div class="right_box"></div>

<div class="right_box"></div>
<div class="right_box"></div>

 <div class="right_box"></div>
<div class="right_box"></div>

 <div class="right_box"></div>
<div class="right_box"></div>

 <div class="right_box"></div>
<div class="right_box"></div>

<div class="right_box"></div>
<div class="right_box"></div>

<div class="right_box"></div>
<div class="right_box"></div>

<div class="right_box"></div>
<div class="right_box"></div>

<br class="clr" />




<div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor  incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</div>
```

css

```
.container {border:1px solid #000; padding: 5px;text-align:justify;}
.right_container{float:right;border: 1px solid #000;background: #f60;padding: 10px;}
.right_box {border:1px solid #000; padding: 5px;background:  #ff0; margin: 10px; float:right; width:50px; height:50px;}
.clr{clear:both;}
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. I believe your suggestion would only work for text. Have a look at the updated picture above and let me know.

Comment: @Chris - more right floating divs would potentially work for you here, see updated jsfiddle

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to achieve your layout using `float`, `border-radius` and `z-index` :

**[FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/qV3FT/1/)**

HTML :

```
<div id="left" class="wrap">
    <div class="img"></div>
    <div class="img"></div>
    <div class="img"></div>
    <div class="img"></div>
</div>
<div class="wrap right">
    <div class="img"></div>
    <div class="img"></div>
</div>
<div class="wrap right">
    <div class="img"></div>
    <div class="img"></div>
</div>
<div id="bottom" class="wrap">
    <div class="img"></div>
    <div class="img"></div>
    <div class="img"></div>
    <div class="img"></div>
    <div class="img"></div>
</div>
```

CSS :

```
body {
    width:1040px;
    margin:0 auto;
}
.wrap {
    background: lightgrey;
    border:5px solid #000;
}
.img {
    border:5px solid red;
    width:150px;
    height:150px;
    background: #fff;
    margin:20px;
    display:inline-block;
}
#left {
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    z-index:2;
    width:440px;
    border-bottom:none;

    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 40px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 40px;
    -moz-border-radius-topleft: 40px;
    -moz-border-radius-topright: 40px;
    border-top-left-radius: 40px;
    border-top-right-radius: 40px;
}
.right {
    float:left;
    width:236px;
    padding:8px 0;
    text-align:center;

    -webkit-border-radius: 40px;
    -moz-border-radius: 40px;
    border-radius: 40px;
    margin-left:40px;
}
.right .img {
    margin: 10px 20px;
}
#bottom {
    clear:both;
    position:relative;
    z-index:0;
    top:-5px;
    padding-top:5px;

    -webkit-border-radius: 40px;
    width: 1020px;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 40px;
    -moz-border-radius-topleft: 0;
    border-radius: 40px;
    border-top-left-radius: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible directly, but you could use a background image to simulate the border/background of your L-shaped element (as the content will already wrap properly if your two small boxes have `float:right`)

Alternatively, if your content is known and static, you could create the effect by having the "top part" and the "wide part" be two separate elements - I did this in some coursework ages ago and impressed the instructor with it XD

Answer (score 0):

You can `float:right` the 2 div elements from the right, and leave the left div go with the  natural flow( `display:block`)

Comment: No, this didn't work for me.