# Wrap textarea input around a div

Tags: html, css, textarea

I've got a textarea field with a `div` box in the top right corner. I've searched far and wide but I can't find a way of having the text which is entered into the textarea wrap around that `div`.

```css
#wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
}

#logo {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
  background-color: cyan;
}

textarea {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>

<body>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="logo">LOGO</div>
    <textarea>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam acumsan fringila lacus, in rhoncus ligula pretium eu. Nulam blandit vel quam ut posuere. Sed tincidunt comodo lacinia. Vivamus eget ulamcorper sapien. Phaselus gravida pretium sem, non fringila orci luctus vel. Donec augue sapien, pharetra portitor fringila hendrerit, ultrices in telus. In aliquet laoret turpis vitae ultrices. Praesent eget nula et telus pelentesque suscipit ac eu est. Nula sed imperdiet dui. Donec eficitur est dolor, nec placerat ex posuere pretium.</textarea>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You want the div centered in the text area ?

Comment: Do you want the div to act as if it were floated to the right? I don't think you can do this... Absolute position takes the div out of the normal flow - text won't be able to wrap around it

Comment: Yes, as if it was right floated. Ideally it would be good to know how to wrap around the div, wherever it is positioned, but for this particular application just having a solution for wrapping around it in the top-right corner would be fine.

Comment: You can add padding to the textarea and the text won't overlap - but it won't wrap around the image. example here --> http://codepen.io/sol_b/pen/LWmVey

Comment: Hah, @ovokuro got there just before me, great minds think alike!! I don't think you can have it wrap around the logo, you could add some padding to the textarea like padding-right: 110px; and then have move the logo back like right: -100px; but the text would just run up to the log, it wont wrap it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this pretty ancient discussion:
[Unusual shape of a textarea?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20728150)

The answer that is given is to use the `contenteditable` property on a `div`.

I manage to get this code that seems to be what you're looking for.

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />

  <style>
    #wrapper {
      width: 500px;
      height: 500px;
    }
    
    #logo {
      width: 100px;
      height: 100px;
      float: right;
      background-color: cyan;
    }
    
    .textarea {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
    }
    
    <html><head><title></title><meta charset="utf-8" /><style>#wrapper {
      width: 500px;
      height: 500px;
    }
    
    #logo {
      width: 100px;
      height: 100px;
      float: right;
      background-color: cyan;
    }
    
    .textarea {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="logo">LOGO</div>
    <div class='textarea' contenteditable='true'>HTML</div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>

</style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="logo">LOGO</div>
    <div class='textarea' contenteditable='true'>HTML</div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

I just replace the `<textarea>` with `<div class='textarea' contenteditable='true'>` and the `position: absolute;` with `float:right;`.

Comment: This is a really good workaround and in essence it works though it seems that chrome has issues processing this code when the div is embedded inside table formatted divs (it works 100% fine in Edge though). Basically the divs which have contenteditable="true" jump around depending on whether they contain any text or not. See here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yMjaPE. Any thoughts how to fix that ?

Comment: Your problems come from your use of display: table and display: table-cell. As you can see here http://codepen.io/Syl-gauthier/pen/XMqeqm (contenteditable being switch off).

Comment: I can suggest you something like that http://codepen.io/Syl-gauthier/pen/evrGKN.
PS: I never used `display: table;` so I don't know exactly where does the problem come from. My guess is that it has somthing to do with the vertical alignment of the text that is different in a table cell and in a normal div.