# text justified in a shape

Tags: javascript, shapes, justify

I'm creating a page with a textarea in which I can write a text and automatically, using js this text (with some modifications) is written in many others element of the page that have the shape of parallelograms (which differ only by dimensions). The problem is not creating such parallelograms, but arrange the text as it appears as written in a parallelogram. I would like also to let text to be justified automatically in that shapes instead of justify manually all shapes by adding spaces.
I have tried using svg and tspan tags, but the problem is that in this way I must manually start new lines and for each different shape lines have different lengths.
shape-outside could be a good solution but it is not supported by many browsers.

Some other ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unusual shape of a textarea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20728150/unusual-shape-of-a-textarea)

Comment: I've tried... In order to have a parallelogram I must create some div tags (1 per text line) and float them left and the same number floating right. Now the problem is how can I float this div tags (for example the once at left) fixing them one under the other? they want to stay all in a single line