# Unusual shaped text area with overflow hidden not working

Tags: html, css

I have found how to make non-rectangular shaped text from here ([Unusual shape of a textarea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20728150/unusual-shape-of-a-textarea)) and it works like a charm.

I need to limit this to 2 lines so I used `overflow: hidden;` but the area somehow returns to rectangular shape.

This is my html code.

```css
.descTitle {
  height: 20px;
  width: 70px;
  float: left;
  border: none;
}

.descContent {
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 20px;
  /*overflow: hidden; /* This breaks the form*/
}

.descOut {
  height: 40px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<tr>
  <td colspan=1>
    <div class='descOut'>
      <div class='descTitle'>
        <label for='txt9'><b>Description: </b></label>
      </div>
      <div class='descContent' contenteditable='true' style='font-color:black; font-size: 11px; font-family:arial'/>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam
      </div>
  </td>
</tr>
```

It works great when I comment out the overflow line but somehow it breaks the form when being used.

Can anyone help me to find out how to limit the contents to 2 lines without breaking unusual shaped text area?

Comment: setting overflow:hidden creates a new [block formatting context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Block_formatting_context) - you might do better to put the overflow hidden part on a parent element or use a different way to handle what you want.

Comment: When I put it in the snippet tool, the opposite seemed true? It looked okay with the hidden attribute but not without? By the way, font-color should be just 'color' (and you may consider using a separate class instead of lots of inline style)

Comment: consider widening the Description width, it overlaps. You may want to consider setting the overflow to auto so that an overflow can still be readable http://jsfiddle.net/cL7pd49z/

Comment: @lemieuxster Huge thanks ! I just moved overflow to the parent and it works perfect! Really appreciate it