# L-shaped div using mask, combined with responsive Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm struggling with creating an L-shaped div (using a mask as in [L shaped div container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20091275/l-shaped-div-container)), combining that with a responsive Bootstrap page.  What I want to create will look like this:

```
------------------------------------------------------------
|                                                           |
|                                                           |
-------------------------------------------------------------
--------------------------------------------------------------
| -----------------------------------   -------------------- |
| |                                 |   |                  | |
| |                                 |   |                  | |
| |                                 |   |                  | |
| |---------------------------------|   |                  | |
|  zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz      |                  | |
|  zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz      |                  | |
|  zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz zzzzzzzzzzz        |                  | |
|  zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz zzzzzzzzzzzz  |                  | |
|  zzzzzzzzzzzzzzz zzzzzzzzz zzzzzzzz   |------------------| |
|  zzzzzzzzzzz zzzzzzzzzz zzzzzzzzzzz zzzzzzzzzzzz zzzzzz zz |
|  zzzzzzzzzzzz zzzzzzzzzzzz zzzzzzzzzzzzzz zzzzzzzz zzzzz   |
|  zzzzzzzzzz zzzzzzzzzzzz zzzzzzzzzzz zzzzzzzzzzz zzzz      |
|------------------------------------------------------------|
```

The divs are variable in height, and I want Bootstrap to manage stacking the divs for small devices. The right inside div can be hidden for small devices, if necessary. If not, I would ilke it to stack under the Z content.

Can I mix-and-match Bootstrap with e.g.

```
 .mask
    {
        border-style: solid;
        border-width: 0 0 3px 3px;
        position: relative;
        float: right;
        clear: none;
        right: -3px;
        top: -3px;
        background-color: white;
        width: 50%;
        height: 4em;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use a float to achieve the layout you want here. Rather than a "mask", you are slotting the image/div to the right hand side of a containing div, and letting the text flow around it.

```css
header {
  height: 24px;
  border: 1px dashed black;
  margin: 4px;
}

article {
  border: 1px dashed black;
  padding: 4px;
  margin: 4px;
  margin-top: 0;
}

.image {
  min-height: 120px;
  min-width: 120px;
  background-color: pink;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<header></header>
<article>
  <div class="image"></div>
  Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content
  Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content
  Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content
  Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content
  Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content
  Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content
  Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content
  Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content
  Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content
  Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content
  Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content
  Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content
  Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content
</article>
```

Comment: Should probably address the overflow of `.image` with a clear fix, too.  It extends outside the `<article>` on large screens.

Comment: @Robert C I'm not sure where that would go. Feel free to edit the answer to make it better :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use `.mask` only to set height of the block. To set the width use `.col-*-*` classes. Use [Responsive utilities](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities) for toggling content across viewport breakpoints.

```css
.mask {
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="mask pull-right col-xs-3 hidden-xs"></div>
<div>
  zzzzzzzzzzzz zzzzzzzzzzzzzz zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz zzzzzzzzzzzz zzzzzzzzzzzzzz zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz zzzzzzzzzzzz zzzzzzzzzzzzzz zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz zzzzzzzzzzzz zzzzzzzzzzzzzz zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz zzzzzzzzzzzz zzzzzzzzzzzzzz zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz zzzzzzzzzzzz zzzzzzzzzzzzzz zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz zzzzzzzzzzzz zzzzzzzzzzzzzz zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz zzzzzzzzzzzz zzzzzzzzzzzzzz zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz zzzzzzzzzzzz zzzzzzzzzzzzzz zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz zzzzzzzzzzzz zzzzzzzzzzzzzz zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz zzzzzzzzzzzz zzzzzzzzzzzzzz zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz zzzzzzzzzzzz zzzzzzzzzzzzzz zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz zzzzzzzzzzzz zzzzzzzzzzzzzz zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz zzzzzzzzzzzz zzzzzzzzzzzzzz zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz zzzzzzzzzzzz zzzzzzzzzzzzzz zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz zzzzzzzzzzzz zzzzzzzzzzzzzz zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz
</div>
```

If you run the snippet, then red div will be hidden. But if you go full page mode, then you will see red block on the top right corner.

Comment: I can see that this is using Bootstrap and fits in with the question that was asked, but don't you find that adding "pull-right" to the container abstracts away a bit of the logic that isn't actually that complex? All it does is add `float: right` to the class...

Comment: @Askanison4, you are right. But the basic idea is to use Responsive utility classes for showing and hiding content by device via media query.

Comment: yeah, I get you. Personally, I'm not a massive fan of device break-points and tend to favour stacking the content in a more flexible way so that I don't have to micro-manage what shows/when :)

Comment: @Askanison4, oh,  yes. I really liked your answer!